# PHP syntax for sql not working

Tags: php, sql

I've been trying to make an update statement for a database but I can't make it work.

Error doesn't show anything either.

What is wrong with the current syntax?

```
$sql = "UPDATE DataFamilie SET Achternaam='$waardeWorden' WHERE Achternaam= 
'$waardeSelect'";
```

Thank you for your help in advance

Edit: It is an MySQL DB.

**It seems like my problem is not in the SQL. I will close this question. Thanks to all of your for helping :)**

Comment: It is an MySQL DB yes

Comment: mh seems pretty fine as query, don't know what the variables contain tho, you can try to print the query with ```echo $sql;``` and run it directly in ```mysql```

Comment: Please use prepared statements or at the very least ensure that you are a escaping the values before passing them into the $sql string.

Comment: Aside from severe sql injection attacks, you should be fine

Comment: I will sanitize later. @gumma Mocciaro , It seems that the echo'd out SQL seems to work. I am certain the problem is not in query atm. Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using single quotes for the php variable you should put it in double quotes

```
$sql = 'UPDATE DataFamilie SET Achternaam="$waardeWorden" WHERE Achternaam= "$waardeSelect"';
```

It will work.